# Puppet (machine) State

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to wrap my head around Puppet, to be able to tweak our automatic build/deployment process.

The one thing that I'm missing at the moment is a concept of a "state" the machine can be in: if I understand it correctly, Puppet assumes that there is one final desired state, and it does everything to reach it and then to maintain it.

However, let's say that I'd like to have my system in different states depending on which part of the system I'm working on (I'm a developer): maybe at some point I want my Riak cluster up and running along with all our service applications. But then I might be working on a bugfix that only affects the UI of the system - I don't need the full Riak cluster or some of the backend machinery. Currently our build/deployment is everything or nothing.

I read about the concept of "stages", but I think it is not what I'm looking for. Is there a way to implement "states" in Puppet?

*PS: I laughed out loudly when I first googled "puppet states". Not exactly what I was looking for* :)

Comment: One approach I've seen used for development systems is to only use puppet for the deployment and provisioning. Once configured according to the base-line specs, de-active puppet and only then hand it over to the developer. Part if the developers job is to document how to come from the existing base-line to a working environment for the new application/release. Stack Overflow may have better existing answers regarding puppet in a development environment.

Comment: I _think_ you're looking for puppet environments.

Comment: @MichaelHampton do you want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Hampton mentioned in the comments enviroments may be what you want, but you may also want something like [roles and profiles](http://puppetlabs.com/presentations/designing-puppet-rolesprofiles-pattern).  With the roles and profiles pattern you apply a profile to a host that sets it up to provide a define set of functions.  So in your case I would imagine you have profiles that describe the various 'states' your machine would be in.  With the Roles and Profiles pattern you normally apply a single profile to a host.

You would then use hiera, or your enc to set the profile for your box to the state you want.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your last sentence? The best I can currently come up with is stopping Puppet, editing `puppet.conf` to change the environment, then restarting Puppet. Is there a better way? (As far as I understand, the roles/profiles setup and Hiera are all about setting up your data - kind of "dependency injection"-style -, but they do not help in managing Puppet lifecycles.)

Comment: A role+profile basically describes how a system is to be configured, which includes the related data at appropriate points.  I would imagine you define a few roles for the various 'states'.  You then go into your ENC/Hiera and set your machine to use a specific profile.